# Not enough input arguements

Tags: matlab

I have the unfortunate task of building a GUI with no experience or education on the topic. The following code will not update the figure without error. I believe it is due to the function `showFIGWINDOW` (line 38 not providing handles for `WALL_L` and `WALL_R` to function `refreshFIG` (line 86).

I feel this is the problem because the functions work when I copy and paste them directly into the command window, but not when I press 'RUN'. How can I overcome the issue "Not enough input arguements (line 115)"

Any help would be outstanding. And please excuse my mess, I'm coding:

```
function Canyon_Racer

close all
clear
clc

WIDTH_LIMIT=.005; %CONTROLS RATE OF WALL CLOSURE
DROP_COUNT=5;
CWALL_L1=0;
CWALL_L2=0;
CWALL_L3=1;
CWALL_L4=1;
CWALL_L5=0;
CWALL_L6=30;
CWALL_L7=30;
CWALL_L8=0;
CWALL_R1=14;
CWALL_R2=14;
CWALL_R3=16;
CWALL_R4=16;
CWALL_R5=0;
CWALL_R6=30;
CWALL_R7=30;
CWALL_R8=0;
CWALL_Y=30;
CLOSE=2;
CWALL_LMAX=1;
CWALL_RMIN=14;
CWALL_TMAX=30;
DELAY=.25;
POLY_NUM=1;
WALL_WIDTH=14;
gameEND=0; %causes game to intiate and continue

% TITLE = ['Welcome to CANYON RUN' 10 10 ' Out run the bandits on your tail to sruvive!' 10 10 '...but don' 10 10 'crash into the canyon walls or you' 10 10 're history' 10 10
%     '    player 1:           player 2:' 10 10 ' use (LEFT) and (RIGHT) arrow keys to stay between the walls' 10 10];

    function showFIGWINDOW

        scrsz = get(0,'ScreenSize');
        fig = figure('Position',[0, 0, 1, 1]);
        set(fig , 'Units', 'Normalized', 'OuterPosition', [0 0 .75 .75], 'color', [127 84 23]./255); %display full screen
        %         CanyonWallX_L = [CWALL_LMIN CWALL_LMAX];
        %         CanyonWallX_R = [CWALL_RMIN CWALL_RMAX];
        subplot('position', [0 0 1 1])
        axis([0 15 0 30])
        hold all
        WALL_L = patch([CWALL_L1 CWALL_L2 CWALL_L3 CWALL_L4], [CWALL_L5 CWALL_L6 CWALL_L7 CWALL_L8], [0 0 0], 'edgecolor', 'none');
        WALL_R = patch([CWALL_R1 CWALL_R2 CWALL_R3 CWALL_R4], [CWALL_R5 CWALL_R6 CWALL_R7 CWALL_R8], [0 0 0], 'edgecolor', 'none');
        set(WALL_L, 'FaceColor', [127 84 23]./255)
        set(WALL_R, 'FaceColor', [127 84 23]./255)
        set(gca, 'XTick', [],'YTick', [], 'color', [184 95 0]./255)
        set(fig,'Name','Canyon Racer v1.0','NumberTitle','off', 'toolbar', 'none', 'menubar', 'none')
        movegui(fig,'center');
        RACER_handle = patch([5 6 5.5], [3 3 5.5], [0 0 0]);

        %%% Check this for uicontrol stuff: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html
        TBX = uicontrol( 'style', 'edit', 'String', 'Hi', 'Position', [.5, .5, 100.5, 15.5] );%%%%%%% DR. V

        %%% Check out the "KeyPressFcn/KeyReleaseFcn portion of this:
        %%% http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure_props.html
        set(fig, 'KeyPressFcn', {@KeyPressed, TBX, RACER_handle} )   %%%%%%% DR. V
        set(fig, 'KeyReleaseFcn', {@KeyReleased, TBX})   %%%%%%% DR. V

    end

    function newGame

    end

    function KeyPressed( src, event, TBX, RACER_handle)   %%%%%%% DR. V
        set( TBX, 'String', sprintf('%s Pressed', event.Key ) );%%%%%%% DR. V
        if strcmp(event.Key, 'leftarrow')
            MOVE_handle = get(RACER_handle,'XData');
            set(RACER_handle, 'XData', MOVE_handle-.1 );
        elseif strcmp(event.Key, 'rightarrow')
            MOVE_handle = get(RACER_handle,'XData');
            set(RACER_handle, 'XData', MOVE_handle+.1 );
        end
    end   %%%%%%% DR. V

    function KeyReleased( src, event, TBX)   %%%%%%% DR. V
        set( TBX, 'String', sprintf('%s Released', event.Key ) );%%%%%%% DR. V
    end   %%%%%%% DR. V

    function refreshFIG( src, event, WALL_L, WALL_R)
        pause(DELAY)

         SPEED_MOVE=1;
%         if DROP_COUNT==5
%             
%             CWALL_L3=randi(CLOSE);
%             while CWALL_L3>CLOSE
%                 CWALL_L3=randi(CLOSE);
%             end
%             if POLY_NUM==0
%                 WALL_L = patch([0 0 CWALL_L3 CWALL_L4], [CWALL_Y CWALL_Y+5 CWALL_Y+5 CWALL_Y], [0 0 0], 'edgecolor', 'none');
%                 WALL_R = patch([CWALL_L4+WALL_WIDTH CWALL_L3+WALL_WIDTH 15 15], [CWALL_Y CWALL_Y+5 CWALL_Y+5 CWALL_Y], [0 0 0], 'edgecolor', 'none');
%                 set(WALL_L, 'FaceColor', [127 84 23]./255)
%                 set(WALL_R, 'FaceColor', [127 84 23]./255)
%                 CWALL_L4=CWALL_L3;
%             elseif POLY_NUM>0
%                 WALL_L = patch([0 0 CWALL_L3 CWALL_L4], [CWALL_Y CWALL_Y+5 CWALL_Y+5 CWALL_Y], [0 0 0], 'edgecolor', 'none');
%                 WALL_R = patch([CWALL_L4+WALL_WIDTH CWALL_L3+WALL_WIDTH 15 15], [CWALL_Y CWALL_Y+5 CWALL_Y+5 CWALL_Y], [0 0 0], 'edgecolor', 'none');
%                 set(WALL_L, 'FaceColor', [127 84 23]./255)
%                 set(WALL_R, 'FaceColor', [127 84 23]./255)
%                 CWALL_L4=CWALL_L3;
%             end
%             if POLY_NUM==6
%                 POLY_NUM=1;
%             end
%             
%         end
        DROP_WALL_L = get(WALL_L, 'YData');
        set(WALL_L, 'YData', DROP_WALL_L-SPEED_MOVE)
        DROP_WALL_R = get(WALL_R, 'YData');
        set(WALL_R, 'YData', DROP_WALL_R-SPEED_MOVE)
%         for NUM=(1:POLY_NUM)
%             DROP_WALL_L = get(WALL_L(NUM), 'YData');
%             set(WALL_L(NUM), 'YData', DROP_WALL_L-SPEED_MOVE)
%             DROP_WALL_R = get(WALL_R(NUM), 'YData');
%             set(WALL_R(NUM), 'YData', DROP_WALL_R-SPEED_MOVE)
%         end
        POLY_NUM=POLY_NUM+1;
        %                 DROP_COUNT=DROP_COUNT+1;
        %         CWALL_LMAX=CWALL_LMAX+WIDTH_LIMIT; %LEFT WALL CLOSING IN
        %         CWALL_RMIN=CWALL_RMIN-WIDTH_LIMIT; %RIGHT WALL CLOSING IN
        %         WALL_L = patch([0 CWALL_LMAX], [CWALL_TMAX CWALL_TMAX]); %POST TO FIG WINDOW
        %         WALL_R = patch([CWALL_RMIN, 15], [CWALL_TMAX CWALL_TMAX]); %POST TO FIG WINDOW
        %         set(WALL_L, 'FaceColor', [127 84 23]./255) %FIG WALL AREA COLOR
        %         set(WALL_R, 'FaceColor', [127 84 23]./255) %FIG WALL AREA COLOR
    end


%Game Primary Script
showFIGWINDOW
newGame
while gameEND==0
    %     moveWall;
    refreshFIG;
    %     checkWALL;
end
% close(fig);
%
%
end
```

Comment: Please use tags to reflect what your question is specifically about, not what your code does that doesn't really matter for the question. Tags do a lot to determine who sees your question; in particular, almost all questions on Stack Overflow have a tag for the programming language. Without this tag, Matlab experts wouldn't have a reason to view your question. See the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for more advice about tags.

Comment: Did you copy-paste the error message? It contains a spelling error (“arguements” instead of “arguments”). It's very important to copy-paste your code and any error messages, including all punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

> I have the unfortunate task of building a GUI with no experience or education on the topic.

Experience and education are unnecessary when you have the excellent [MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/) at your disposal.

This error happens because the [graphics handles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/understanding-handle-graphics-objects.html) `WALL_R` and `WALL_L` are defined in the [nested function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/nested-functions.html) `showFIGWINDOW` but are used in another nested function, `refreshFIG`. To have these handles visible in both nested functions, they should be defined in the parent function. So, add the lines

```
WALL_L=0;
WALL_R=0;
```

At the beginning of the main function (say, after `WALL_WIDTH=14;`).

This however is not enough, as these handles are wrongly redefined as arguments to `refreshFIG` in the line

```
function refreshFIG( src, event, WALL_L, WALL_R)
```

so when this function is called, these handles, defined in the parent function, are hidden by the arguments of the same name (which are undefined in the call to `refreshFIG`). To solve this, remove the handle names from the function argument.

After this the game seems to run smoothly, but it's kinda boring, even compared to [some other canyon racing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_krCKECpzrU) ;)

Comment: Using a global variable is exactly what it takes to run this properly. Thank you! My Professor is asking me to use handles and callbacks and I'm just not understanding the concept behind it. Thank you so much, this knocks it back into my wheelhouse.

It is boring, but since this is an intro class the fact that the walls update is an accomplishment of its own. It will have other things, short cuts, booster, difficulty will increase with closing walls and then (if there's time) obstacles. Beyond that it is just a lame 2-D 3rd person game from a second year engineering student. 

Thanks again!

Comment: I was joking :) for a first project it is quite an accomplishment. If you find the answer satisfactory, please accept it. Good luck on your course.